# How to design a study and test the effect of dosage level on cure probability?

Tags: logistic, experiment-design, interpolation

My goal is to quantify dosage impact on cure probability for different patients. Let's suppose I have N patients with their charateristics such as age, gender, weight.... Also let's assume there is a known range for dosage, say from 0 to 1.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

1. Randomly split all patients into 3 groups
2. Group 1 is given dosage of 0.1, group 2 dosage of 0.5 and group 3 dosage of 0.9. Please note size of group is different. Presumably group 1 is largest because I need decent number of cured patients and I know low dosage leads to low cure probability. Also note that I can not test more dosage because N is limited.
3. Get outcome (0/1) for all patients
4. Train logistic regression model for each group
5. If I want to get cure probability for any particular patient with untested dosage (say 0.7), I just calculate 3 probabilities based on models in step 4 and do some simple interpolation.

My question is if there is any better way to do this. I'm not feeling very comfortable about the interpolation part.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't vary dosage along your scale continuously, and treat dosage as a continuous variable? You'd get a far better picture of the relationship between dose and response that way.

Comment: Experiment results are given and I have to find a way to deal with it. Agree with you that treating dosage continuously is a better approach and will definitely suggest it if I'm consulted for the next experiment.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways in which you could try to get the possible outcome for the untested dose (say 0.7).

**Preferable way**

Since you have covariates for each patient (i.e., age, gender, etc., say $\mathbf x$ (a vector)), dosage ($d$), and the response ($0/1, y$), fitting a logistic regression with $y$ as response and $(d, \mathbf x)$ as covariates is the easiest way to model the dependence of $y$ on $d$. Once you have trained your logistic regression model on the available data, you could predict for any patient in the future, given you have their covariate $(d_{\text{new}}, \mathbf x_{\text{new}})$ information by

$$
p_{\text{new}}=\frac{\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_d d_{\text{new}} + \mathbf{\beta}_{\mathbf x}^' \mathbf x_{\text{new}})}{1 + \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_d d_{\text{new}} + \mathbf{\beta}_{\mathbf x}^' \mathbf x_{\text{new}})}
$$

Because you have trained your logistic regression before, you should have a cutoff $c$ for deciding the possible outcome such that

$$
p_{\text{new}} > C \implies 1
$$
$$
p_{\text{new}} \le C \implies 0
$$

**Your way**

Lets say you train 3 separate logistic regression models based on 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9 with unequal group size, and you could predict probabilities $p_{0.1}, p_{0.5},$ and $p_{0.9}$ for a particular dose (say 0.7).

A meaningful way of interpolation to determine the probability (only if you insist on it), could be

$$
p_{0.7} = \frac {\displaystyle \sum_{i \in \{0.1, 0.5, 0.9\}} w_i p_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{i \in \{0.1, 0.5, 0.9\}} w_i}
$$

where the weights could be decided in various ways. A few options are:

1. $w_i = \frac{n_i}{(i-0.7)^2}$, where $i$ is 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9, and $(i-0.7)^2$ reflects the "closeness" of the new dosage to the original 3 groups and $n_i$ is the number of individuals in the ith groups controlling for higher confidence in the weights with higher $n_i$.
2. $w_i = \frac{n_i}{|i-0.7|}$, where $i$ is 0.1, 0.5, and 0.9, and $|i-0.7|$ reflects the "closeness" of the new dosage to the original 3 groups and $n_i$ is the number of individuals in the ith groups controlling for higher confidence in the weights with higher $n_i$.

However, I would not be very confident in these methods as they are based on a lot of assumptions and "hand-waving".

Comment: I considered the preferable way too, ie put dosage explicitly in the model as a continuous variable. However given the fact that experiments have already been done for only 3 dosage values (0.1 0.5 and 0.9), which way will generate better predictions, especially for those dosage values not tested? Thanks!

Comment: I think the logistic regression is a better way (preferable way) as long as you are interested in determining the relationship between dosage and response. It doesn't matter if you did the experiment only for 3 doses.